Finale: Human Playback off for one effect
I am using Finale (2024) to create short music theory examples, and generally they're greatly improved by using human playback on (because they're mostly classical).  However, because they're music theory examples, I'm often adding additional analytical notes using expressions in a new, custom category.  Most of these expressions don't do anything to playback, just as I'd like.  However, some of them, like labeling the tonic area as "T" have unusual playback -- Finale interprets anything beginning with a T in any font as "play a turn here" which is pretty amusing but makes the audio unusuable.
I've tried using the expression designer's Playback to turn Human Playback Off, but it doesn't work (and even if it did, I don't want Human Playback off, I just don't want a turn).  I've found that some Playback types do seem to disable default behavior.  Currently I'm setting the "T" to set Controller 78 (Sound 9) to 127 -- which doesn't do anything in my setup (I don't have a controller on sound 9) but it does disable the trill.  Is there something else I should be doing instead to make this work properly?

Weird.  In real notation, T is occasionally used for a trill.  It is odd to treat it as a turn.

The guys at Finale Forum (not connected with Make Music) may be able to help.https://www.finaleforum.com/index.php?sid=ef75429e05e4a4aeabe0740420a224ef

As usual, the easiest suggestion is "make a new copy for audio purposes and change as necessary."

Oh, I've also set it to Playback only on Pass 99 (i.e., never playback) -- the effect isn't played but the Turn is also not played.
